# Configuring Postfix to use milter (archiveSMTP)

Tags: postfix, socket, milter

How does one config Postfix to use the milter "archiveSMTP" ?

The milter config instructions (http://www.dancingfortune.com/projects/archivesmtp/download.php) mention only one socket for communication between the milter and the MTA

... yet any Postfix docs I read use two sockets  - one for the milter to listen on for messages *from* the Postfix queue and a second for reinjection back *in* to the Postfix queue.

So following a Postfix tutorial (Postfix: The Definitive Guide) I add

```
 archive   unix  -       -       n       -       10              smtp 
    -o myhostname=localhost
```

to *master.cf* for messages *to* the milter. And enable this in *main.cf* with

```
   content_filter = archive:[127.0.0.1]unix:/var/run/archivesmtp/mta.sock
```

(I'm reasonable sure this is correct as the archiveSMTP documentation gives a Sendmail example and calls this socket (unix:/var/run/archivesmtp/mta.sock) the **Input** MailFilter)

The Postfix tutorial goes on to define another socket (in inet format this time) like so:

```
 localhost:10026 inet n  -  n -  10 smtpd
```

(again in master.cf)

for the reinjection to the Postfix queue.

...except archiveSMTP makes no mention of a second socket.

Answer (score 2):

Postfix offers a few different ways to filter/scan messages. It seems that you have tried "*Postfix after-Queue Content Filter*" instead of "*Postfix before-queue Milter support*".

URL(s):

- http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html#config Postfix and milter integration